# while writing a Chaincode (Hyperledger-fabric) in Golang I am confused while fallowing documentation

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I am confused ,when I am following fabric-samples (asset-transfer-basic --->https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go/chaincode/smartcontract.go)  for writing smart contract in Golang , the methods takes ctx contractapi.transcationcontextinterface   as  there function parameter , but when I am trying to refer other chaincode's on internet every one else are taking   stub shim.chaincodesubinterface  as there function  parameter , if I use  stub  as my function parameter then how can I make use of  clientidenty methods (cid package) , and in asset-transfer-basic code Init/Invoke are not mentioned  also in main function when creating a new chaincode  ( assetChaincode, err := contractapi.NewChaincode(&SmartContract{})  )  SmartContract{}  does not implement contractinterface . I am try to do a project on ERC20 token for applying for jobs so please help

Answer (score 0):

The examples you have found that include an Init and Invoke function, and take ChaincodeStubInterface as a parameter are using the older and lower-level [fabric-chaincode-go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go) API directly. The asset-transfer-basic sample is using the newer and higher-level [fabric-contract-api-go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go) API. This is built on top of the lower-level API and allows you access to all the same information as the lower-level API (note that the transaction context passed into transaction functions using the higher-level API has a [GetStub](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go/contractapi#TransactionContextInterface) method to obtain the corresponding low-level ChaincodeStubInterface).

I would recommend using the Contract API as demonstrated by the asset-transfer samples. The two approaches are functionally equivalent but the Contract API provides a cleaner abstraction requiring less boiler-plate code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it cleared a lot of my doubt's